# How to change the default python version on anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

Whenever I run python on Anaconda or atom, it automatically defaults to an environment I made called "tf15".

When I do `where python` in my cmd I get the right path `C:\Users\Kelfun\Anaconda3\python.exe`

But when I run this in my jupyter notebook or atom text editor:

`import sys
print(sys.executable)`

I get: `C:\Users\Kelfun\Anaconda3\envs\tf15\python.exe`

How can I make the "root" environment as my default environment in Anaconda.

Also, I did not activate "tf15" before opening jupyter or atom yet it defaults to it.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have probably added `C:\Users\Kelfun\Anaconda3\envs\tf15\Scripts` to your system's PATH variable ahead of the base Anaconda3 path.  The kernel for your 'tf15' environment is not in the `\Scripts` folder, so you are seeing the correct path when using `where python`.

To fix it, open the system variables interface (Start Menu > type `variable` > click "Edit the system environment variables")

Check the PATH variable for both the system and the user for anything that points to `C:\Users\Kelfun\Anaconda3\envs\tf15` and remove them.

Comment: Nothing in my PATH variables have tf15 in it.

Comment: Perhaps your jupyter script got messed up?